# OnChange Void issue using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have written a code on React BoilerPlate using typescript and onChange on a select box, need to update the state of the parameter.

I have tried initialState passing data `onChange` function, below is the code

```
export const initialState = {
  currencyRate: '',
  currencyCode: 'USD',
};

const changeCurrency = (state = initialState, args: any) => {
    produce(state, currency => {
      currency.currencyCode = args.target.value;
    });
    console.log(currencyCode);
  };

<select id="currency" name="currency" onChange={changeCurrency(
                { currencyRate: '', currencyCode: '' },
                null,
              )}
            >
```

I need to set value `onchange` to `currencyCode` state

Below is the error

> TS2322: Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event:
>   ChangeEvent) => void) | undefined'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export const initialState = {
  currencyRate: '',
  currencyCode: 'USD',
};

// `const...` is equivalent to `function changeCurrency(event: ChangeEvent) {...}`
const changeCurrency = (state = initialState, args: any) => {
  // return a function with expected signature by onChange
  return (event: ChangeEvent): void => {
    produce(state, currency => {
      currency.currencyCode = args.target.value;
    });
    console.log(currencyCode);
  }
};
```

```html
<select id="currency" name="currency" onChange={changeCurrency(
    { currencyRate: '', currencyCode: '' },
  null,
)}
>
```

Answer by Mehran Hatami is also correct, if not preferable.

Answer (score 1):

To explain the problem we should format your code properly:

```
export const initialState = {
  currencyRate: '',
  currencyCode: 'USD',
};

const changeCurrency = (state = initialState, args: any) => {
  produce(state, currency => {
    currency.currencyCode = args.target.value;
  });
  console.log(currencyCode);
};

return (
  <select
    id="currency"
    name="currency"
    onChange={changeCurrency({ currencyRate: '', currencyCode: '' }, null)}
  >

  </select>
);
```

If you look closer to the way you are passing the onChanhe event you would notice that instead of passing a function to onChange you are actually passing the result of a function call to it. Lets rewrite part of your code to understand it better:

```
const result = changeCurrency({ currencyRate: '', currencyCode: '' }, null);
return (
  <select
    id="currency"
    name="currency"
    onChange={result}
  >

  </select>
);
```

This is exactly what your code does, I only created a variable for the result of the function call. The next step is for you to see what are you actually returning in your function. The answer is nothing or void and that's why you are actually passing a void to the `onChange`. Considering this explanation if you read the error message again:

> Type 'void' is not assignable to type '((event: ChangeEvent) => void) | undefined')

you would understand it better.

The easiest way to resolve is to pass a function to the onChange like this:

```
return (
  <select
    id="currency"
    name="currency"
    onChange={(event) => {
      changeCurrency({ currencyRate: '', currencyCode: '' }, event)
    }}
  >

  </select>
);
```

Comment: Hi Mehran..

Your code resolved my void issue but got new issue onchange
"Cannot read property 'target' of null"

Also, need to print the value of the selected option

Comment: @dhawalm you were passing null to the function call, to resolve that you have to pass the event instead of null. made a small change, try again

Comment: Are you sure your options all have value?

Comment: also i have added <p>{currencyCode}</p>. But data is coming blank

Comment: It probably means the data is not flowing correctly into your props or you are not handling your state properly. Make sure u call setState in your function.

Comment: sorry to bother you, but I am new to React Typescript. Do we have state & setState in Typescript

Comment: @dhawalm create a small piece of codebase using https://jsfiddle.net or https://codepen.io/ using whatever you are using and share the link so that we know exactly what is your bare minimum component structure looks, then we can answer with more details.

Comment: @dhawalm of course as a different question. you can send the question link here.